# Remove/Hide QuickActionGrid

Tags: java, android, greendroid

I create grid in my function like that:

```
grid.addQuickAction(
         new QuickAction(
                 context.getActivity(),
                 themeService,
                 R.string.msg,
                 12));
grid.addQuickAction(
         new QuickAction(
                 context.getActivity(),
                 themeService,
                 R.string.msg2,
                 13));
```

where `grid` is `QuickActionGrid grid = new QuickActionGrid(context);`and I gets it as parameter, now I need to hide or remove the first one. The only solution I've found is `grid.getQuickAction(0).setEnabled(false);`
but it is still there, only I cannot click on it. 
So how can I hide or remove the first element from grid? I cannot change class it has to be`QuickActionGrid`

Comment: why don't you try grid.getQuickAction(0).setVisibality(View.GONE)

Comment: @R7G because I have no such option?